# Unable to get bolt out of door

Tags: lock, deadbolt

I'm unable to get the bolt out of a door. For a couple days before it was sticky, and you could push in the bolt on the inside of the door frame to functionality "reset" it  so that the lock would turn.

Unfortunately it's jammed inside of the door frame and I'm unable to get it out.

I've removed the lock coverings and am using a screwdriver to turn the inside mechanism but it doesn't seem to be catching anything and I don't feel any movement of the deadbolt itself. The only thing that is moving is the little tab above the cylinder.

[image] 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bolt may possibly be held in the door frame by friction due to misalignment. If this is vertical misalignment, using a prybar under the edge of the door and shifting the door up a little may allow the bolt to retract. If that doesn't do it, then use the prybar to shift the door down a little and see if that frees the bolt.

If the misalignment is in-and-out, then pressing or pulling on the door while trying to manipulate the bolt may allow it to retract.

**Edit**
You may be able to accomplish the same thing by prying (gently) on the exposed end of the lock in the hole in the door. But it sounds like the bolt has become uncoupled from the mechanism which retracts it. You may have to drill out or cut off enough of the visible mechanism to allow the bolt to be manipulated through the hole in the door.

**EDIT 2**

See http://www.doityourself.com/forum/residential-commercial-security-devices-door-knobs-locks-keys-dead-bolts/517772-deadbolt-will-not-retract-all-way.html#b

Answer (score 4):

If you are saying the bolt is extended into the frame and won't retract, try pulling the hinge pins and removing the door by "opening" the door on the hinge side.

Comment: This is the best answer. So obvious once stated but never thought of when you get into a pickle. There are sometimes door hinges that have a security pin on one side that engages a hole in the other hinge side when the door is in the closed position. Unfortunately the trick in this answer will not work in the case security pins are present.

Comment: Also the bolt may be so long that when you remove the hinge pins the door cannot be removed. But clearly this is the step to try next. I hope the OP will  report the resolution.